# How to update a column for two separated ids?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have these two queries:

```
$dbh
->prepare("UPDATE user
            SET reputation = reputation - 15
            WHERE id = ?")
->execute(array($old_author));

$dbh
->prepare("UPDATE user
            SET reputation = reputation + 15
            WHERE id = ?")
->execute(array($new_author));
```

I want to know can I do that by one single query? I mean can I both `- 15` and `+ 15` in `reputation` column for two users in the same query?

Comment: yes, but its smarter to use 2

Comment: @Dagon Why two separated queries is better? I think one single query is much faster ..

Comment: debugging, rollback, maintainability. your " much faster" will be insignificant in 99.99% real world situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `case` expression to do it in one query.

```
UPDATE user
SET reputation = case id when '123' then reputation - 15
                         when '124' then reputation + 15  
                 end
where id in ('123','124')
```